# Error in overwriting zeros array "could not broadcast input array from shape (8,1) into shape (8,)"

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, casadi

```
import numpy as np
          
x0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
xx = np.zeros((8, 20))
xx[:,0] = x0
```

I want to overwrite zero arrays columns but it gives an error as:

> could not broadcast input array from shape (8,1) into shape (8,)

Comment: Which numpy version are you running? Your code works in my 1.18.5 environment

Comment: I'm guessing your example doesn't accurately represent your problem.  The error is giving a different shape for `x0`.  Try `xx[:, 0] = x0.squeeze()`

Comment: What is `x0`? The real one.

Comment: x0 is casADI DM zeros matrix, I want to convert it into a one-dimensional vector.